# Why use the prefix -webkit- when @keyframes works?

Tags: html, css, webkit

Why is -webkit- used when @keyframes works, at least on chrome? There are many other prefixes. Do I need to use them all for all the browsers to support an animation?

Answer (score 0):

Vendor prefixes (which happily are being used less and less by browser implementors) are designed to let web developers try out *experimental* features.

Now `@keyframes` (and its Chrome implementation) are no longer experimental, the standard property has become supported.

Answer (score 0):

That's called a vendor prefix. Browsers usually use these prefixes for features that are experimental or sometimes are not based on any standard.

Since the features are experimental using them is not recommended for production. But if you want to use them you have to use all the common prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

Safari too uses webkit. There's no telling how many browsers will share prefixes in the future or whether every OS runs the prefixes as efficient.
If you know web responsive designing then you know compatibility and back ups are important. 
-moz-
-ms-
-webkit-
-o-
You'll find yourself adding these prefixes later on because browsers run differently.
But to be honest, I don't use them until I really have to. Just make sure it works everywhere!